# Is this question about TeX software appropriate

Tags: discussion, request-for-information, scope

I looked at the FAQ but couldn't quite tell if this question is appropriate.

I want to ask for advice on how to fix TexWorks on my computer. I installed Miktex which came with TexWorks, but tried to update to the newer version of TexWorks. It installed, but cannot compile any tex commands. I can't find much in the way of documentation to fix this.

Again, sorry if this is completely inappropriate, but I figured it would be better to ask on meta first.

EDIT: I have solved the problem, but I am still curious if the question is still appropriate.

Comment: A related thought: should questions which are editor-specific always get tagged with the editor name? I'm thinking 'yes', but perhaps others disagree.

Answer (score 2):

The most appropriate place for help concerning difficulties after installing a piece of TeX-related software, like TeXworks, is probably the [mailing list](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/texworks) for that software.  You will reach the greatest amount of experts in that way.

If you have found what you think is erroneous behavior, filing a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/texworks/issues/list) is probably the best thing to do.

The reason is that the resolution to these issues is highly specific to either the way your computer is configured or the way TeXworks installs.  Using the project-specific mailing list or bug tracker will put the issue and its resolution at a location that specifically focused on these issues.  This is a more relevant place than a Q&A site that operates under the wide umbrella of "questions about TeX and friends".

Answer (score 1):

There was a [similar question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/are-questions-about-related-applications-ok) some days ago. The answer then was that, yes, this questions are fine. But as other guys have already pointed out, you'll probably find more prompt/helpful advise by contacting the mailing-list or the developers of the application in question.

As a side note, I've just created the [[scope]](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) tag so that we can group together and quickly find these “Are question about [...] OK?” more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that this is quite a tough one to be definitive on. There are questions that do fit (such as 'how to install TeX on ?') and some that are at least getting answers ('How do I do X in editor Y?'). That said, the editor-specific mailing lists are going to have much higher chance of people having come across a particular editor-related issue. I think we have to be flexible, and try to be helpful while suggesting alternative routes for support.